# Find two elements of $S_4$ that are generators of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

> A presentation of the alternating group $A_4$ is
> $$ A_4 =\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^3=1\rangle $$
> Find two elements of $S_4$ that represent $a$ and $b$.

The representatives of $a$ and $b$ that I have to find are two elements $A$ and $B$ in $S_4$ such that

$$A^2=B^3=(AB)^3=1$$

I tried with $A=(12)(34)$ and $B=(123)=(12)(13)$ and it works, but I chose those elements quite at random and I had to do the whole calculation to check it.

Here is the full calculation of $(AB)^3$ ($A$ is denoted by $\to$ and $B$ by $\longrightarrow$)
$$ 
\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{2,1,4,3\}\longrightarrow\{3,2,4,1\}\\\to\{4,1,3,2\}\longrightarrow\{4,2,1,3\}\\\to\{3,1,2,4\}\longrightarrow\{1,2,3,4\}
$$

Is there a faster and/or clever way to find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia has some nice tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group#Examples_S4_and_A4

Comment: When you say that you chose them "at random" I think you meant that you chose some element of order $2$ and some element of order $3$, than noted the product had order $3$? This is not a surprise, in $A_4$ it doesn't matter which such pair you choose the product will always be of order $3$.

Comment: And you'd simplify your calculation by noting $AB=(134)$.

Comment: Yes, by "at random" I meant that; I didn't know that in $A_4$ a product of elements of order 2 and 3 yields an element of order 3. Why does it happens? So you think the "hard part" was finding an element of order 2 and an element of order 3? You are right about the simplification, I didn't think of that. Thank you @ancientmathematician